# Dask-distributed. How to get task key ID in the function being calculated?

Tags: python-2.7, distributed, distributed-computing, dask

My computations with dask.distributed include creation of intermediate files whose names include UUID4, that identify that chunk of work.

```
    pairs = '{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(list1, list2, list3, ...)

    file_path = os.path.join(job_output_root, 'pairs',
                             'pairs-{}.txt'.format(str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')))

    file(file_path, 'wt').writelines(pairs)
```

In the same time, all tasks in the dask distributed cluster have unique keys. Therefore, it would be natural to use that key ID for file name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to approach the problem:

1. You determine the uuid and pass it to Dask (implemented)
2. Dask determines the uuid and passes it to your function (not implemented, but possible)

#### You pass the uuid to Dask

Functions like `.submit` accept a `key=` keyword argument where you can specify the key that you want used

```
>>> e.submit(inc, 1, key='inc-12345')
<Future: status: pending, key: inc-12345>
```

Similarly dask.delayed functions support a `dask_key_name` keyword argument

```
>>> value = delayed(inc)(1, dask_key_name='inc-12345')
```

#### You get the key from Dask

The scheduler places contextual information like this into a per-thread global during the execution of each task.  As of Version 1.13 this is available as follows:

```
def your_function(...):
    from distributed.worker import thread_state
    key = thread_state.key

future = e.submit(your_function, ...)
```

Comment: First variant is enough. Doest it work with `map` in the same fashion? Looks like not...

Comment: Indeed not.  Submit-in-a-for-loop should work fine though