# get the name of the dask delayed object/task from within the original function?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Suppose I have some function

```
def f(x):
    y = ... # do something
    return y
```

that I then delay and compute:

```
result = dask.delayed(f, name='Jim')(x, dask_key_name='Jim')
result.compute()
```

Is it possible to get the name `Jim` from within `f`? Can I ask the worker for the key associated with the current task?

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330017/dask-distributed-how-to-get-task-key-id-in-the-function-being-calculated) and the following gets me something that might be useful but it isn't `Jim`, it's something generated by dask:

```
import dask.distributed
dask.distributed.worker.thread_state.key # Not "Jim"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
def f(x):
    return dask.distributed.get_worker().get_current_task()

d = dask.delayed(f)(0, dask_key_name="Jim")
assert d.compute() == 'Jim'
```

Which internally uses the `active_threads` property to look up the task associated with the current thread.